# How to perform sort on documents based on type selected dynamically and then sort by amount

Tags: sorting, marklogic

Requirement:

1. Search results return list of purchase orders
2. Purchase order may or may not have a line-item (for purposes of example)
3. There can be thousands of line items for a purchase order
4. There will only be 1 line-item for a type (no duplicates within the purchase order)
5. For sorting:

   6. We’ll know what type has been selected to sort by and only want sort order based on the amount for that specific type
   7. Only 1 type will be selected for sorting
   8. Other use cases can sort of different elements

Sample document:

```
<purchase-order>
  <line-items>
    <line-item type=lamp  amount=3500 </line-item>
    <line-item type=couch  amount=50000 </line-item>
    <line-item type=chair  amount=40000 </line-item>
  </line-items>
  <other-stuff></other-stuff>
</purchase-order>
```

Comment: It would be appreciated if you would share code, showing what you have tried so far. Best way to learn, is from your own mistakes. Note: your xml sample is not well-formed..

Answer (score 0):

First, your xml is not well-formed:
I have used below xml and query:

```
     let $input :=
          <purchase-order>
           <line-items>
            <line-item type="lamp"  amount="52"/>
            <line-item type="lamp"  amount="40000"/>
            <line-item type="lamp"  amount="3500"/>
            <line-item type="lamp"  amount="3500"/>
            <line-item type="couch"  amount="50000"/>
            <line-item type="chair"  amount="110000"/>
            <line-item type="chair"  amount="5000"/>
            <line-item type="chair"  amount="80000"/>
          </line-items>
          <other-stuff></other-stuff>
        </purchase-order>

         let $purchase-order := 
          for $each-type in distinct-values($input/line-items/line-item/@type)
          let $seq := $input/line-items/line-item[@type = $each-type]
          order by $each-type
          return 
             <line-items type="{$each-type}">
             {
             for $one in $seq
             order by xs:integer($one/@amount)
             return $one
             }
             </line-items>
             return <purchase-order>{$purchase-order}</purchase-order>
```

Output generate by query:

```
              <purchase-order>
                <line-items type="chair">
                <line-item amount="5000" type="chair"/>
                <line-item amount="80000" type="chair"/>
                <line-item amount="110000" type="chair"/>
                </line-items>
                <line-items type="couch">
                <line-item amount="50000" type="couch"/>
                </line-items>
                <line-items type="lamp">
                <line-item amount="52" type="lamp"/>
                <line-item amount="3500" type="lamp"/>
                <line-item amount="3500" type="lamp"/>
                <line-item amount="40000" type="lamp"/>
                </line-items>
              </purchase-order>
```

Hope you requirement will full-fill this query.

Comment: Thank you @Akbar aLI  for replying to my post. Our requirement was different and we have the solution. For details please refer to below post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55183482/how-to-do-selective-sorting-by-attribute-based-on-associated-value-of-element-or