# How to do Selective Sorting by Attribute based on associated Value of Element or other Attribute in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Requirement:

1. Resolve directly through Index, don't want to open the documents (Hence, Not considering FLOWR expression).
2. Search results return a list of purchase order documents
3. The purchase order may or may not have a line-item (for purposes of example)
4. There can be thousands of line items for a purchase order, each with a different type
5. There will only be 1 line-item for a type (no duplicates within the purchase order)
6. For sorting:
      Based on one of the many types selected by user at the time of search (sometime chair and sometime lamp etc..)
      Sort order based on the amount for that specific type Only (for example: chair)

Sample document 1:

```
<purchase-order>
  <line-items>
    <line-item type="lamp"  amount="3500"></line-item>
    <line-item type="couch"  amount="50000"></line-item>
    <line-item type="chair"  amount="40000"></line-item>
  </line-items>
 <other-stuff></other-stuff>
</purchase-order>


Sample document 2:

<purchase-order>
  <line-items>
  <line-item type="couch"  amount="10000"> </line-item>
  <line-item type="chair"  amount="80000"></line-item>
 </line-items>
 <other-stuff></other-stuff>
</purchase-order>
```

Expected Result sequence:

- Request to sort doc by the amount desc for type chair should return the sequence of doc 2 and 1
- Request to sort doc by the amount desc for type couch should return the sequence of doc 1 and 2

Comment: You will likely need to create a path index for each of the types, like `line-item[@type = "couch"]/@amount`, and define a separate sort-order for that. Are you using the MarkLogic REST-api?

Comment: @grtjn ,  We are not using MarkLogic REST-api, but instead search:search api thru XQUERY
We will have thousands (assume 3k max) of types.
Would this then require up to 3k path indexes to be defined?
Can you also clarify what you meant by "define a separate sort-order"

Comment: @grtjn , What would contribute to memory consumption for a specific type's path index (i.e. "couch"), any documents with:
 Hoping no memory consumption for docs only having a thru d below:
   a) /purchase-order
   b) /purchase-order/line-items
   c) /purchase-order/line-items/line-item
   d) /purchase-order/line-items/line-item[@type of anykind] i.e. "chair"

 Hoping memory consumption only for:
   e) /purchase-order/line-items/line-item[@type = "couch"]

Comment: Concern would be if memory consumption for a specific type's path index would be increased due to documents not having the specific type for that index.

Comment: Yes, 3k path indexes. Each would only include docs with matches, so no mem for non-matches.

Comment: With sort-order I meant http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_44212 With saved search options you'd have to spell out 3k sort orders too, but if you generate options on the fly you could simplify that part. Sort-order must be backed by a range index though.

Comment: Wondering if triples and optic api could provide a more dynamic solution, but not sure..

Comment: We are currently in ML-8 and do need to address this issue in the near term so ML 9 is not an immediate option.
Unless I'm missing something, In ML-8, I don't see the sorting via a path-index being addressed, specifically sorting based on a specific type (i.e. sort amount for chair vs sort amount for lamp).

Comment: It is supported in v8, just use <path-index>..

Comment: Thank you for your Help. 
 
 This looks like it's functionally working for us:
 
 Created a Path Index:
  "/purchase-order/line-items/line-item[@type = "couch"]/@amount"
 
 With Query Option:
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
   <sort-order direction="descending" type="xs:decimal">
    <path-index>/purchase-order/line-items/line-item[@type = "table"]/@amount</path-index>
   </sort-order>
  </options>
 
Still, have some concern with a large number of path indexes, but will further evaluate/test that part. 
 
 Thank you Again!